# How to attach multiple parameters to an API request?

Tags: express, vue.js, axios

I built my own simple REST API with Express and now I'm consuming it from my client (Vue.js)

So in my page I access all the data from this endpoint: `GET /api/books`, and it works fine

Now I also have a "sort by" button where I want to get the data by the latest entries. I don't know if that's a good way or if I have to handle this in the backend but what I do is calling the same endpoint which is `GET /api/books` and sorting the data to get them the right way

For ex:

```
sortByLatest() {
  axios
    .get("/api/books")
    .then(res => {
      const books = res.data;
      const sortedBooks = books.sort((a, b) => b.createdAt > a.createdAt ? 1 : -1
      );
      this.books = sortedBooks;
    })
    // catch block
}
```

I do that for everything. If I need a limited number of results or a specific property from the data I have to write some logic in the axios `.then` block to sort or filter what I want. Is this bad practice?

**But that's not my actual problem**

My problem is, in addition of sorting by the latest entries, I also want to filter the results by a specific property. The problem is when I click the `A button` it's gonna filter the books by a specific property, and when I click the `B button` it's gonna sort them buy the latest entries, but not both at the same time!

And what if I want additionnal things like limit the number of results to 10, filter by other properties etc... I want to be able to create requests that ask all those things at once. How can I do that? Do I have to build that in the backend?

I saw some websites using url parameters to filter stuff, like `/genre=horror&sort=latest`, is that the key of doing it?

Thank you for your time

Comment: depends on how much data you need to sort/filter.  if it's always going to be small, just return the raw data from the server and sort/filter in javascript.  however large datasets often need to be paginated, which defeats the purpose of sorting/filter on the client side if you don't have all the data to work with.

Comment: Send query params to an API using either GET `axios.get('/user?foo=bar&baz=meh')` or POST `axios.post('/user', {foo: 'bar', baz: meh' })`. See more examples [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#example). Fetching all DB and filtering it in FE defeats the purpose of having a BE in the first place. What you're doing now is about as good as shipping the entire DB in the app as `.json`.

Comment: @Erich What I exactly want to do is to **save** my filters. For example if I click a button to sort the data by the latest and then I click another button to filter the data by a specific genre, I want the data to be display by this specific genre *and* by the latest. Right know I can't, I can only do one thing at the time. I don't know if I'm clear, let me know if not. If so, do you have any guide or something that explains how to accomplish that?

Comment: @tao Thank you! That's what I needed but didn't know I could. Regarding my answer to @Erich about saving the filters, I guess what I should do is storing my filters as query parameters (like when I click a button to sort by the latest entries, the url goes `/books?sort=latest` and if I click another button to filter by genre It's going to be `/books?sort=latest&genre=horror` ) and then updating my api request with it?

Comment: Your question is too general. In principle, you want a `<form>` with form controls pertaining to each query parameter. When a form control changes, you send a request with the form value and replace the results of your list with the response. That's the gist of it.